# Xcode cannot run using the selected device No provisioned iOS devices are available

Tags: xcode, profile, provisioning, jailbreak

One of my coworkers set me up with a provisioning profile through our corporate profile. I have read through several tutorials and none of them corresponded to the steps he actually took to get it set up. In the end my device was listed under the devices section of the organizer with a green circle next to it (I am guessing that's good?) but when I try to run the application on my device I get the error I mentioned in the subject of this post. I should mention my device is jailbroken running iOS 4.2.6. Is the "jailbrokenness" of my device an issue?

This is like day one with Xcode and it is pretty overwhelming coming from the Linux command line and Emacs. I don't expect a complete walk through from any of you. But if you can point me to a nice long tutorial showing me how to set this up with the latest version of Xcode I would appreciate it.

[image: Screenshot for warning]

Answer (score 2):

Check if you can see your device in Organizer and verify iOS version installed on the device with the deployment target for your application. This is very often the case as you won't be able to deploy 4.3 application to 4.2.1 device (for example).

Comment: Sorry I don't know where anything is yet. I found something else to play with when I ran into this issue so I still have no time with the tools. Are you referring to a project setting buried in some menu or can I change this under the "scheme" selection. The scheme selection says 4.2.6 overriding Base SDK to 4.3. I know my iOS version is 4.2.6 but I am not sure what all needs to match.

Comment: Never mind I found it. I played with that setting before but this time I created a new project from scratch and paid really close attention to all of the settings and everything worked out. Now I can start learning :-) I want to use the gyro and accelerometer to build a Kalman filter.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode Set the target to project_name | iOS Device

Then in Xcode From the product menu=>Build For=> Build For Testing